# Can I disable Android PNG crunching for a product flavor rather than build type?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, aapt

In the Android Studio guide to optimizing build speed, they mention that you can disable PNG Crunching by adding `crunchPngs false` to your build type, like follows:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Disables PNG crunching for the release build type.
            crunchPngs false
        }
    }
```

However, I also have multiple product flavors defined, and I'd like to disable PNG crunching for all builds which use a specific flavor. If I try the following:

```
 android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
        }
        ...
    }

    productFlavor {
        internal {
            crunchPngs false
        }
        ...
    }
```

It fails, because `crunchPngs` is only defined on `BuildType`. I'm not super familiar with the relationships between build type and product flavor - is there any way to disable PNG Crunching for a product flavor?